# Removing an SSL certificate without breaking links

Tags: .htaccess, ssl

Over the course of the last year a site I maintain with a payment gateway has stopped taking payments or collecting any user information. Seeing an opportunity to save a few bucks, we let the SSL certificate lapse.

The problem I am facing now is that Google and other sites have linked to the `https` version of my site. Whenever any of these links are visited you, rightly, get a security warning.

I added the following to my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

But I'm still hitting the warning page every time I visit the site via an `https` link.

How can I get around this? In my head, for it to be failing the .htaccess file is being read *after* you visit the site, but Chrome is blocking the page before that stage – is that correct? If not, it may just be that I have a typo in my htaccess file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any kind of redirection is done after the TLS handshake, this means you get the warnings before the browser even gets the information that it should redirect.
And to anticipate a typical follow-up question: fiddling with DNS (i.e. CNAME etc) will not help either.

That means that you either accept the warnings about the broken certificate or you get a new certificate for your site.